# server socket loose binding

Tags: java, c, linux, linux-kernel

I want to develop master server and secondary server.

When the master server is down secondary server should come up on the same port.

But when master server is ready to start secondary server should gracefully stop so that master server can start on the same port.

**Is there any way secondary server can know that another process is trying to start on the same port?**

Comment: Whoever voted to close this as 'not a real question' is only showing their own ignorance.

Comment: Hmm, master and slave server on the _same_ machine? That is quite a bizarre setup

Comment: Edited to highlight the **specific, real question** being asked.

Answer (score 3):

If what you need is to have your server up always, you can follow this method,

Create a parent process which will spawn a child to do the actual service by listening on the port. When child is serving actual requests, the parent would wait for child to die (crash/state change) by using `waitpid` in `C`. So whenever child goes down, the parent knows and spawns new process. - *preferred approach*.

---

If you need master-secondary design in particular,

When secondary is serving request, it can always wait for signal from master server. So when master is up, its first task would be sending that signal to secondary when it finds that the secondary is up(either through pid file or file lock or bind failure), so that the secondary can gracefully close.

Comment: Interesting - what if the secondary were the launch parent of the primary, and it could use something like sigchild to tell if that died?

Comment: Similar to that. I personally design server to have parent and children where parent is only to monitor children using `sigchild` and spawn it whenever it goes down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a direct way to detect that process is *trying* to listen on a given port, short of intercepting the actual attempt with a debugger hook such as a ptrace, or more likely shared library substitution using LD_PRELOAD.

However, if you can modify the source you could fairly easily have one process inform another, and ask it to kindly get out of the way.  You could do this using various means of interprocess communication, such as contacting it on the port it is listening on (beware security implications), contacting it on a different port (listening on the loopback interface only!), contacting it on a unix domain socket, and many other choices.

To tell if another process is already listening, you can use `netstat` or use information exported from /proc directly yourself to look at the in-use sockets.

Beware that unless the original server used the SO_REUSEADDR flag, you may suffer a timeout before a different process can claim that port.  That may argue for running your backup on an alternate port, and having the clients try it as a fallback.  Or for having a simple process which functions as a port forwarder to either of the two servers' unique ports.